# Delayed Write Error

Tags: c#

I developed a backup program for my important directories.

This program writing is the data to a disk on a USB flash drive. Sometimes i get an error:

```
delayed write failed (id:50)
```

Is there any way to solve it in C# ? Writing directly to the DOK by using flags wasn't successful. it's probably caused by the cache but I can't disable it via the policies of the DOK.

The copy method:

```
FileInfo backupFile = file.CopyTo(theDokDir + fileToCopy.Name);
```

Comment: Hi @Help.  Can you copy/paste into your question the code where the file writing occurs?  That could be a starting point to someone helping you find the problem

Comment: I have also tried to copy with filestream  - same result

Comment: DOK it's a Disk on Key, flash drive

Comment: Do you, by any chance, remove the USB device without properly "ejecting" it ("safely remove hardware" or whatever the localized name is) by using the the unplug or eject hardware icon in the taskbar's notification area?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [this Microsoft Support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816004) can help you:

> [...]
>   An event ID 50 message is logged if a generic error occurs when
>   Windows is trying to write information to the disk. This error occurs
>   when Windows is trying to commit data from the file system Cache
>   Manager (not hardware level cache) to the physical disk. This behavior
>   is part of the memory management of Windows. For example, if a program
>   sends a write request, the write request is cached by Cache Manager
>   and the program is told the write is completed successfully. At a
>   later point in time, Cache Manager tries to lazy write the data to the
>   physical disk. When Cache Manager tries to commit the data to disk, an
>   error occurs writing the data, and the data is flushed from the cache
>   and discarded. Write-back caching improves system performance, but
>   data loss and volume integrity loss can occur as a result of lost
>   delayed-write failures.
>
> [...] Programs can set a FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING flag that bypasses
>   Cache Manager. [...] An event ID 50 message never
>   results from non-buffered I/O. [...]

Additionally, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48679/314334) or [this post](http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/2010/01/19/writing_file_with_non_cache_mode_in_c/) may be helpful

PS: Have you tried to use another USB Flash Drive?

Comment: Yes, I tried another drive and I used that flag - didn't solve the problem. Is there any way to catch and prevevnt the balloon message(without changing the registry)?. It will be ok if i not solving the problem but only prevent from  the balloon to be shown.